# Numerical methods for Mellin transformation of real data in Python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I have real data which formatted as a set of x,y data. I would like to conduct a Mellin Transformation on this data and find Mellin Image.

There is a python package [sumpy integrals](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals) that can be used for [Mellin tranformation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.transforms.mellin_transform)

The syntax is rather simple as can be see from the example below:

```
from sympy.integrals.transforms import mellin_transform
from sympy import exp
from sympy.abc import x, s
mellin_transform(exp(-x), x, s)
```

I have tried to use UnivariateSpline to fit my experimental data first and later feed it into mellin_tranform in a functional representation. It did not work, I got an error that does not mean much to me.

my code, where 'spl' is the result of UnivariateSpline fit of the data.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('testData.dat')
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
x, y = data[:,0],data[:,1]
w = np.isnan(y)
y[w] = 0.
spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, w=~w, s = 0.001)

from sympy.integrals.transforms import mellin_transform 
from sympy import exp 
from sympy.abc import s 

# Using mellin_transform() method 
gfg = mellin_transform(spl, x, s)
```

And traceback

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py:455: SymPyDeprecationWarning: 
    
    String fallback in sympify has been deprecated since SymPy 1.6. Use
    sympify(str(obj)) or sympy.core.sympify.converter or obj._sympy_
    instead. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18066 for more
    info.
    
      deprecated_since_version='1.6'
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    ValueError: Error from parse_expr with transformed code: "<Symbol ('scipy' ).interpolate .fitpack2 .UnivariateSpline object at Integer (0x7fd3dd282350 )>"
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py in sympify(a, locals, convert_xor, strict, rational, evaluate)
        471         a = a.replace('\n', '')
    --> 472         expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
        473     except (TokenError, SyntaxError) as exc:
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py in parse_expr(s, local_dict, transformations, global_dict, evaluate)
       1025             local_dict[i] = None
    -> 1026         raise e from ValueError(f"Error from parse_expr with transformed code: {code!r}")
       1027 
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py in parse_expr(s, local_dict, transformations, global_dict, evaluate)
       1016     try:
    -> 1017         rv = eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
       1018         # restore neutral definitions for names
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py in eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
        911     expr = eval(
    --> 912         code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
        913     return expr
    
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    SympifyError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-43-69182e8c8178> in <module>
          4 
          5 # Using mellin_transform() method
    ----> 6 gfg = mellin_transform(spl, x, s)
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/integrals/transforms.py in mellin_transform(f, x, s, **hints)
        384     hankel_transform, inverse_hankel_transform
        385     """
    --> 386     return MellinTransform(f, x, s).doit(**hints)
        387 
        388 
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/cache.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
         74                 if not e.args or not e.args[0].startswith('unhashable type:'):
         75                     raise
    ---> 76                 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
         77             return retval
         78 
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py in __new__(cls, *args, **options)
        471 
        472         evaluate = options.get('evaluate', global_parameters.evaluate)
    --> 473         result = super().__new__(cls, *args, **options)
        474         if evaluate and isinstance(result, cls) and result.args:
        475             pr2 = min(cls._should_evalf(a) for a in result.args)
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/cache.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
         74                 if not e.args or not e.args[0].startswith('unhashable type:'):
         75                     raise
    ---> 76                 retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
         77             return retval
         78 
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py in __new__(cls, *args, **options)
        273         from sympy.sets.sets import FiniteSet
        274 
    --> 275         args = list(map(sympify, args))
        276         evaluate = options.pop('evaluate', global_parameters.evaluate)
        277         # WildFunction (and anything else like it) may have nargs defined
    
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py in sympify(a, locals, convert_xor, strict, rational, evaluate)
        472         expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
        473     except (TokenError, SyntaxError) as exc:
    --> 474         raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
        475 
        476     return expr
    
    SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '<scipy.interpolate.fitpack2.UnivariateSpline object at 0x7fd3dd282350>'' failed, because of exception being raised:
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Does anyone have a working example or better documentation on how to do Mellin transformation numerically in python?

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

I can only give some clues about what can be the problem because i could not make your code run without the file of data.

To my mind, their was 2 problems in your approach:

1. problem of argument type when computing the mellin transform. You had

   ```
   # Using mellin_transform() method 
   gfg = mellin_transform(spl, x, s)
   ```

   while one can read on [simpy documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.transforms.mellin_transform) that the calls are done this way:

   ```
   from sympy import mellin_transform, exp
   from sympy.abc import x, s
   mellin_transform(exp(-x), x, s)
   ```

   The main difference between the two is that you passed "spl" as argument of the Mellin transform. "spl" is a callable (i.e. a function) while spl(x) would be a array i guess.

   The example below comes from [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html) and you can see that spl is a function.

   ```
   spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y)
   xs = np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000)
   plt.plot(xs, spl(xs), 'g', lw=3)
   ```

   I think, you should have evaluated it like "spl(x)" in the Mellin transform.
2. problem of concept. Simpy is a package that helps doing formal math. Then Simpy is able to provide the mellin transform expression as long as a closed form (i.e. exact formula) is known ([see here simpy doc](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.transforms.mellin_transform)). In your case of spline curves, such closed forms may not exist.